# Does the length of the keyword used for keytable for Playfair matter?

Tags: cryptanalysis, keys, key-size, playfair

So for Playfair, we choose a keyword and put that in the keytable with no duplicates. Then, we fill the rest of the table with alphabets in order that are not in the keyword without 'J'.

Does the length of the keyword matter? I am wondering because I wanted to know whether having just a random 25 characters long word for the keytable would be more secure than choosing a word that is less than 25 characters long and filling the rest of the table with the rest of the alphabets in order.